# How to remove the empty options in a select box?

Tags: html, forms

i have a select box which is really simple but it keeps outputting empty options which i don't have these options. why is this?

```
<form id ="orderby" action="" method="post">
    <select name="orderby"style="float:right;">
        <option selected="true" style="display:none;">choose view order</option>
        <option value="ASC" >Ascending<option>
        <option value="DESC">Descending<option>
    </select> 
    <input type="submit" value="Arrange" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no empty options. Your problem is because of not closing properly second and third `option` tags. Try this:

```html
<form id ="orderby" action="" method="post">
   <select name="orderby"style="float:right;">
     <option selected="true" style="display:none;">choose view order</option>
     <option value="ASC" >Ascending</option>
     <option value="DESC">Descending</option>
   </select> 
   <input type="submit" value="Arrange" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your selected option is set to `display:none`, either remove that or set one of the other options to selected.

Small detail you should use `selected="selected"` instead of true.